# How to add the folder names (../../../) into an image name in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a `code.php` file similar to below which generates images like `-this-is-a-test-21.jpg` in a `all-photos` folder.

```
foreach($original_images as $new_image) {
 ---> some coding here
$image_prefix_original = "-this-is-a-test-";
$rand = rand(1,100);
 ---> some coding here also
imagejpeg($new_image, $image_prefix_original .$rand.'.jpg');
 }
```

Assume that I'm executing the `code.php` file as `http://localhost/tests/photos-test/all-photos/code.php`. My question is how to generate the image name like `tests-photos-test-all-photos-this-is-a-test-21.jpg` instead of `-this-is-a-test-21.jpg`.

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking for your directory separator to be a hyphen?

Comment: On most installs, `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is usually `/`. Have you specified it to be `-`?

Comment: You can't use the system directory separator character in a file name.

Comment: @i-CONICA, sorry for not being clear, basically image `-this-is-a-test-21.jpg` is generated in `test-photos/test/` path (i.e. `test-photos/test/-this-is-a-test-21.jpg`). I just want to add the folder names into the image name (i.e. `test-photos/test/test-photos-test-this-is-a-test-21.jpg`)

Comment: this is ridiculous. if you want to use that name, **write** that name in the code. it's that simple.

Comment: @Apiah: I don't see why. if you don't tell us (exactly) what your real problem is, we can't help.

Comment: I think you are looking for the _____DIR_____ "magic constant". Once you get the directory, you can parse it and prepend it to the filename. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I edited the question, could you please see the question again?

Comment: @BenM, thank you Ben, if possible, please take a look at the question again, hopefully it's more clear

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is to put the directory separator into the file name, then as said, you cannot have the directory separator, whatever that is on your system, within a filename. You need to look into how filesystems work, especially on Unix systems. Everything is a file, a file is a file, a folder is a file, a printer is a file, a hard drive is a file. If you had the directory separator as part of a file name, it would be chaos.

**but...**

If what you're asking is to mimic the directory structure within the filename, replacing the directory separator with a hyphen, then that's totally possible, try;

```
$image_name = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "-", $image_prefix_original);
```

This will take your image with path, and give you a new name containing the path elements separated now with a hyphen instead of the slash.

Comment: thanks for your response, I edited the question, could you please review the question again?

Comment: I have, I think you're asking all the wrong questions. You're trying to achieve something in an obscure way when there's a much simpler way  of doing it. Also, you cannot use rand to generate file names, as you'll quickly run into clashes. You should just hash the image and use it's hash as the filename as the chances of collisions are into the big numbers.